# C# Winforms GridView ComboBox Column SelectedItemIndex

Tags: c#

How can I select a specific value in the combobox column in the datagridView using its index?

I.e. the comboboxColumn is already populated. I just need to set its selectedIndex to my choice (if it is possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose you have a dataGridView with 1 column (your comboboxColumn), and you want to set the cell(0, 0) value to index 2:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = comboboxColumn.Items[2];
```